# How to run shell script using php

Tags: php, linux, shell, background

I have a php file

```
<?php
$op=exec("/usr/bin/sh /home/muralik/www/html/testing/testin.sh >> /home/muralik/www/html/testing/abc.log 2>&1 &",$rs);
echo "OP = ".$op;
echo "<br>RS = <pre>";
print_r($rs);
echo "</pre>"
?>
```

**testin.sh**

```
while(true)
do
echo "standard output"
echo "abc"
sleep 2
done
```

When i open the php file in localhost or web server. the shell script is not running.

What should i do. thanks in adavance.

Comment: What is the output when you run the script?

Comment: Nothing i found in abc.log and empty in web page request.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your script is running, you're just not seeing the output?

The command you're running in your exec redirects both STDOUT and STDERR to abc.log:

```
/usr/bin/sh /home/muralik/www/html/testing/testin.sh >> /home/muralik/www/html/testing/abc.log 2>&1
```

Because everything is getting redirected, nothing will end up in $rs, and $op will be empty as well as there will be no last line from the executed command.

Also, your shell script is going to run in an infinite loop, meaning it will never return anything, meaning the exec() should never return as it waits for the execution to finish.

Comment: When i run in command prompt it running fine. But when i am trying to invoke from WEB Browser its not running.

Comment: Which are you running in the prompt?  The shell script or the PHP file?  As mentioned in the answer, you've got an infinite loop in the shell script, so nothing will return to the browser, though if you did a `tail -f /home/muralik/www/html/testing/abc.log` while you tried to run the PHP, I'd imagine you see the file updating every two seconds (or as output buffer flushes occur). . .

Comment: ernie: i have tail -f /home/muralik/www/html/testing/abc.log the file is empty...

Even i opened that file and saw. nothing present in the file....

Thanks in adavce..

Comment: Once could you try on ur system and do let me know na... It working when i run .php file on terminal..

Comment: When i run the same .php file in terminal

i can see tail -f /home/,,,,,/abc.log containing standard output and abc...

Answer (score 0):

Usually (for security reasons) scripts run from a browser will not run shell commands.

In order to make it work you need to change your .htaccess file (this will tell your server to treat your script as an appliacation)

Add the following lines in your .htaccess:

```
Options ExecCGI 
AddHandler cgi-script .php
```

This will allow any php files in the CGI folder to run as an application

Comment: Could you tell me where does .htaccess file presents? @pzirkind

Comment: Could you tell me where can i edit .htaccess file. I am on ubuntu and LAMP Stack @pzirkind

Comment: usually in the root folder of your website - but beware that by default ubuntu ignores them if you need help enabling them see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles